# How to plan out a theatre using labels

Tags: arrays, vb.net, label

For a school project, we have to develop a theatre booking system, with a graphical representation of the theatre, which is labelled in a really annoying way. Our tutor said we should represent the theatre with a 2-d array of labels, but referencing each label to change the colour is tricky, say if the user booked seat 10,10 then that wouldn't be 10,10 in the array.

Does anyone know of any good methods of solving this? Because I am stumped.

Here is a link to the seating plan:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/U14ut.png

Comment: we can help if you are stuck, but do let us know where you are stuck first!

Comment: the point of assign/hw is that you get good with logic on your own, if we give you the logic, what is the point of studying?

Comment: Sorry, I've done most of the program, all of the file i/o and inputs/outputs.

Comment: If a user types in say 10, 10 referring to the theatre plan, is there a way I can turn that into a co-ordinate in the array of labels?

Comment: well looking at the fig a array of [11, 20] seems fine

Comment: if a user books 10 tkt, u dont need a 10, 10 array, u simple keep the users selected positing, a common can be implemented this way : unique_position = row_num * 20 + col_no

Comment: well you question is more of explanation then coding!

Comment: So will I just have to convert what the user inputs into the program to different coordinates in the array, but in the same position? Or can I like invert the way the array is referenced to?

Comment: that is why i said its more of explanation work!

Comment: I wonder if the tutor meant array in the programming sense or just in the sense of a bunch of labels laid out on a form to match the layout of the seating plan. Also the user will presumably not type in 10,10 but something like C10. Or perhaps they will actually click on a seat/label in your on-screen plan. One way forward would be to store the seat plan code - C10 - say in the tag property of the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you use an array of labels for each row. For example for row A create labels named `lblRowA` with indexes 1 to 14 and repeat for the other rows (having an array for each row). That should make it easy to map requests onto real world seating.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the 2-D array of labels, you can use two 2-D arrays of the same size, one for the row letter and one for number of each seat represented by the array of labels.

For example, for `labels(4, 7)` the seat number might be `seatNumbers(4,7)` and the row letter might be `rowLetters(4,7)`.

If you know how (or can figure it out), you use one 2D array of a class or structure where each member contains the two values, and possibly reservation information, etc. In that case, you could address the seat information with something like `seats(4,7).rowLetter`, `seats(4,7).seatNumber`, and `seats(4,7).reserved`. You could also have a reference to the seat labels in the `seats` class.